# std::min_element on list does not return the minimum

Tags: c++, list, minimum

I have a `while` loop that initialize a `list` with some `double`s.

I would like to output the smallest value but what I have done so far seem not be working, because I don't get any output.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
    list<double> allDistances;

    std::ifstream infile("ATXTFile.txt");
    while (std::getline(infile, data)) {

        //do some stuff
        //dist are some double values
        allDistances.push_back(dist);
    }

    cout << min_element(allDistances.begin(), allDistances.end()) << endl;

}
```

Comment: We don't know. Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: Also please define "doesn't work". Compile error? Runtime error? Incorrect result?

Comment: since ther's not an example I 'll try to guess. are you doing something like `auto it = min_element` and then printing the actual minimum element using `*it`? `min_element` return an iterator  and not the minimum itself.

Comment: What doesn't work?
Show us what you do, what happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question, tell me if it's fine for a clarification

Comment: _"it doesn't work, I don't get any output"_ I would expect you to get a compile error. What really happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the way you print the minimum

The following will work:
`cout << *min_element(allDistances.begin(), allDistances.end()) << endl;`

#### Why?

Because `min_element` returns an iterator to the minimum not the minimum itself.
If you need the actual value, you had to dereference the iterator returned by `min_element`.

You can see it from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) that the signature of `min_element` is:

```
template< class ForwardIt > 
ForwardIt min_element( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last );
```

and that it returns a `ForwardIt` i.e. a forward **iterator**

Comment: This also finally explains why I don't need to write extra an iterator. Great, thank you!